# Winston-daily-rotate ignores maxFile size

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, winston

I am currently trying to set the maxSize in my winston daily rotate file, but the file always reaches a size of 121 kb and then later creates another file no matter what value is set for the maxSize here is the code I'm usin

```
            const transport = new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
            filename: '%DATE%_log_file.txt',
            dirname: path.join(__dirname, '../../', 'logs'),
            datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-mm',
            maxSize: '20m',
            maxFiles: '2d'
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was having minutes in date format. Since my code runs for longer than a minute the transport updates the filename which in turn creates another log file since the time has changed.